# OwinStartup and startup in signalr in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

i have a problem with SignalR in asp.net mvc
i add a package below:
[image]

and add Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Paksh.Startup))]
namespace Paksh
 {
   public class Startup
    {
      public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
       {
                  app.MapSignalR();
       }
     }
 }
```

but i get error:

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>   - The OwinStartupAttribute.FriendlyName value '' does not match the given value 'ProductionConfiguration' in Assembly 'Paksh, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   - The given type or method 'ProductionConfiguration' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly.
>   To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error...

> The given [...] method 'ProductionConfiguration' was not found.

Means that the [OWIN Startup Class Detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) was looking for a method called `ProductionConfiguration` on the type you provided (`Paksh.Startup`), but could not find it. Something tells me that you have something similar to this in your **web.config** as well:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:appStartup" value="ProductionConfiguration" />       
</appSettings>
```

You have several options to solve this:

1. Change the name of the `ConfigureSignalR` method to `ProductionConfiguration`
2. Specify the correct method name in the [`OwinStartupAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270663(v=vs.111).aspx): `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Paksh.Startup), "ConfigureSignalR")]`

To get to know the OWIN startup class detection, read more [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error to OP, but using attributes instead of `web.config`. I had:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("Configuration", typeof(StartUp))]
namespace WebPipes
{
    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDB");

            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        }
    }
}
```

The parameters in `OwinStartup` were incorrect, the first parameter denotes the *friendly name*, not the method name. The following code does work, though:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartUp), "Configuration")]
namespace WebPipes
{
    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDB");

            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        }
    }
}
```